# Text Editor Seems to Works in <textarea> but not when displayed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a blog system where I use a form to create a blog post. Here's what the form looks like: http://prntscr.com/7wupnn (As you can see, I've made a bit bold and changed the colour).

Here's the source of that form:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db_connect.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
header('Location: login.php');
exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$title = $db->real_escape_string($title);
$body = $db->real_escape_string($body);
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
$body = htmlentities($body);
if($title && $body && $category){
$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO posts (user_id, title, body, category_id, posted) VALUES('$user_id', '$title', '$body', '$category', '$date')");
if($query){
echo '<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 40px; left: 500px; padding: 10px; background: red; box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; color: #fff;">Post Added</div>';
}else{
echo '<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 40px; left: 500px; padding: 10px; background: red; box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; color: #fff;">An unexpected error has occured.</div>';
}
}else{
echo '<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 40px; left: 500px; padding: 10px; background: red; box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; color: #fff;">Please enter all the required information to proceed</div>';
}
}
?>


<div id="mainbox">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Post Title Here">
<p></p>
<textarea name="body" id="mytextarea" cols=50 rows=10 placeholder="Enter Post Content Here"></textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'mytextarea' );
</script>
<p></p>
<input type="file" name="upfile">
<select name="category">
<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
echo "<option value='".$row->category_id."'>".$row->category."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

When I click submit, the post is then published onto the blog page - however it's lost all it's style - here's what I mean: http://prntscr.com/7wuq9f - as you can see, the browser is displaying the HTML rather than using it.

Here's the code for he blog page:

```
<?php
include('blog/db_connect.php');
$record_count = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
$per_page = 2;
$pages = ceil($record_count->num_rows/$per_page);
if(isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])){
$page = $_GET['p'];
}else{
$page = 1;
}
if($page<=0)
$start = 0;
else
$start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, LEFT(body, 100) AS body, category FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=posts.category_id order by post_id desc limit $start, $per_page");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $category);
?>

<div id="mainbox">
<?php
while($query->fetch()):
$html_body = nl2br($body);
$lastspace = strrpos($html_body, ' ');
?>
<h2><?php echo $title?></h2>
<p><?php echo substr($html_body, 0, $lastspace)."<a href='blog/post.php?id=$post_id'>..</a>"?></p>
<p>Category: <?php echo $category?>
<hr />
<p></p>
<?php endwhile?>

<?php
if($prev > 0){
echo "<a href='blog.php?p=$prev'>Previous Page</a>";
}
if($page < $pages){
echo "<a href='blog.php?p=$next'>Next Page</a>";
}
?>
```

Instructions on how to keep the style of the text when publishing it would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not loading the CKEditor Javascript file from what I can see.

Comment: I'm including that in my header.php, but I didn't paste that bit of the code in my thread. I can use the editor fine when creating the post, but when I publish it, it seems to not recognize the HTML - take a look at my screenshots to see what happens.

Comment: Actually, if I recall, CKEditor uses an "htmlentities" for the content within the textarea, so the HTML is not naturally rendered.  Try using htmlspecialchars on the content when you display the post.

Comment: So what would I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: My best guess would be `$html_body = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($body));`

Comment: Tried that, but sadly it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: htmlspecialchars _should_ render the content out as HTML.  Anyway you could possibly show me the database row from MySQL?

Comment: Which database row would you be referring to? The posts? Let me just say the form for creating the post works fine if I don't use CKEditor - this shouldn't be the case though.

Comment: I would like to see how the HTML is "stored" in MySQL whether it's htmlentities or just the plain old tags.  The row would be the one containing the blog post that was submitted from CKEditor.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're asking.. I didn't create any MSQL entries for CKEditor, but I did the the default textarea:  http://prntscr.com/7wwseu http://prntscr.com/7wwsh9

Comment: It seems like they're being stored correctly.  Try this `<p><?php echo $body; ?><a href="blog/post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">...</a></p>`

Comment: What do you recoomend doing? I could do a screenshare and show you what happens..

Comment: Still no luck - it just displays the HTML code http://prntscr.com/7www10

Comment: Try asking the guys over at CKEditor.  I believe they have a forum and allow questions.  Sorry I couldn't help you :(